# How to disabled/suppress parts of a jQuery dataTable from rendering?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have just set up my first [jQuery dataTable](http://datatables.net) and would like to customize it's look-and-feel:

[image]

Specifically, I'd prefer that four areas underlined in red not be visible to the user:

- "*Show 10 entries*"
- "*Showing 1 to 1 of 1 entries*"
- The whole "*Search*" area (label and textfield)
- Both the *Previous* and *Next* pagination buttons

Is this possible? If so, how? I can't find the docs that mention how to suppress table components. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confucius say, *Give a man a fish > teach a man to fish.*

Just add the following to the inside of your datatable def:

```
"sDom": 't'
```

Enjoy.